# how to extract the file name from file uri

Tags: android, file, filenames

I made a app to upload files to `firebase` storage and set it to `firebase`. All is working fine, but when i upload a file, the file uploads to `firebase` successfully, but it renames to a unique name(for `System.currentTimeMillis())`, how i keep its original name?
(I tried the `getLastPathSegment().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$",""))` but it didn't work.

```
    private void uploadFile(Uri pdfUri)
        {
            //uploading progress dialog
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading file...");
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.show();


          final String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf"; //TODO use System.currentTimeMillis() if you want a unique name
           final String fileName1 = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";


            StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference(); //returns parent path
```

Comment: Please remove all code irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Then start with your url so we can see how it looks like.